# Creating an OSX PyQt app using Pyinstaller 2, PyQt4 and Qt5

Tags: macos, pyqt, qt5, pyinstaller

I am trying to package a PyQt program for OSX using PyInstaller 2, where PyQt4 (4.10) has been built against Qt 5.0.2 (from Git). The following simple example doesn't work.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMessageBox

def main():
    print "Hello"
    a = QApplication(sys.argv)
    m = QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Information, "Title", "Hello")
    m.exec_()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Spec file generated using pyinstaller-2.0/utils/MakeSpec.py and modified to add the BUNDLE class.

```
a = Analysis(['hello.py'],
         pathex=['/Users/glenn/rp/src/demo'],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=None)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=1,
      name=os.path.join('build/pyi.darwin/hello', 'hello'),
      debug=False,
      strip=None,
      upx=True,
      console=False )

coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=None,
           upx=True,
           name=os.path.join('dist', 'hello'))

app = BUNDLE(coll,
        name=os.path.join('dist', 'hello.app'),
        appname="Hello",
        version = '0.1'
        )
```

Packaging command

```
> python pyinstaller.py --windowed hello.spec
```

Running the binary directly from the terminal gives this output before it crashes:

```
$ ./dist/hello.app/Contents/MacOS/hello 
Hello
Failed to load platform plugin "cocoa". Available platforms are: 

Abort trap: 6
```

and this is the stack trace:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x9a671a6a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x93163b2f pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9319a4ec abort + 168
3   QtCore                          0x03db156b qt_message_fatal(QtMsgType, QMessageLogContext const&, QString const&) + 11
4   QtCore                          0x03db19df QMessageLogger::fatal(char const*, ...) const + 63
5   QtGui                           0x068abceb QGuiApplicationPrivate::createPlatformIntegration() + 3547
6   QtGui                           0x068abd16 QGuiApplicationPrivate::createEventDispatcher() + 38
7   QtCore                          0x03f4f2c4 QCoreApplication::init() + 100
8   QtCore                          0x03f4f23b QCoreApplication::QCoreApplication(QCoreApplicationPrivate&) + 59
9   QtGui                           0x068aa0d0 QGuiApplication::QGuiApplication(QGuiApplicationPrivate&) + 32
10  QtWidgets                       0x06c695de QApplication::QApplication(int&, char**, int) + 238
11  PyQt4.QtGui.so                  0x06394454 init_QApplication + 196
12  sip.so                          0x007bc7d5 sipSimpleWrapper_init + 266
13  Python                          0x0385c174 type_call + 340
14  Python                          0x0380d401 PyObject_Call + 97
15  Python                          0x0389c093 PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 10131
16  Python                          0x038a0490 fast_function + 192
17  Python                          0x0389beae PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 9646
18  Python                          0x038998b2 PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 1922
19  Python                          0x03899127 PyEval_EvalCode + 87
20  Python                          0x038be06e PyRun_StringFlags + 126
21  Python                          0x038bdfb1 PyRun_SimpleStringFlags + 81
22  Python                          0x038bf619 PyRun_SimpleString + 25
23  hello                           0x00003240 runScripts + 240
24  hello                           0x0000280a main + 442
25  hello                           0x00001eb9 _start + 224
26  hello                           0x00001dd8 start + 40
```

The issue appears to be that it can't find the libqcocoa.dylib plugin. This is not surprising as it is not packaged. Is that the actual issue here and do I need to include this plugin? If so where does it need to go? I have tried putting it in demo.app/Contents/plugins but that doesn't help.

Comment: I tried with Qt 4.8.1, Pyside 1.1.1, the latest dev version of Pyinstaller, on OSX 10.7.5, without your fix to the spec, and it also crashes. I could not test your fix to the spec because libqcocoa.dylib does not exist on my computer? Difference between PySide and PyQt?  Meanwhile, a slightly larger program that opens a mainwindow doesn't crash until you close the app.

Comment: The issue with libqcocoa is specific to Qt5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right place to put libqcocoa.dylib is in `Contents/MacOS/qt4_plugins/platforms`:

```
extralibs = [("qt4_plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib", "/path/to/libqcocoa.dylib", "BINARY")
             ]
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries + extralibs,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=False,
               name=os.path.join('dist', 'hello'))
```

The app now starts but the dialog window never appears. Edit: This is because PyInstaller (v 2.0) adds LSBackgroundOnly=true to the apps Info.plist. Removing this allows the window to show.

Comment: I was having a similar issue and the reason was that I had to change some paths depending if I was running from pyinstaller or not. Setting LSBackgroundOnly to False made two icons appear in my dock

Comment: There is a discussion about the LSBackgroundOnly and double icon issue here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyinstaller/f3800Jc0rr0

Answer (score 1):

Try adding (but changed for PyQt):

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
```

At least that works for me (PySide 1.1.1, Qt 4.8.1, latest dev Pyinstaller, OSX 10.7.5, with no changes to the spec file and --onefile --windowed arguments to pyinstaller.)  And without this snippet, it also crashes for me.

I suppose that pulls in more dependencies.

Found this in another answer.

Comment: The question is specific to Qt5.