# Create .exe with Pyinstaller ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found

Tags: python, pyinstaller

First I'll mention that I'm using Python 2.7.6 through the Anaconda distribution on Windows 7.

When running `pyinstaller --onefile MyScripy.py` I am only getting one error which is the one mentioned in the title and the exe is created. When running the exe there are some issues using the ctypes library which I beleive are related to said error.

I get this error a total of 12 times in the output from the pyinstaller command. Here is the complete output:

```
2776 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.sax
2807 INFO: Processing hook hook-pyexpat
3338 INFO: Processing hook hook-matplotlib
3602 INFO: Processing hook hook-sysconfig
3602 INFO: Processing hook hook-parser
4430 INFO: Processing hook hook-setuptools
4601 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32com
4616 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32com.client
4616 INFO: Processing hook hook-pythoncom
4680 INFO: Processing hook hook-pywintypes
4757 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32ui
5240 INFO: Processing hook hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph
5349 INFO: Processing hook hook-PIL
5365 INFO: Processing hook hook-PIL.Image
5444 INFO: Processing hook hook-Image
5661 INFO: Processing hook hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin
6473 INFO: Processing hook hook-pytz
6661 INFO: Processing hook hook-lxml.etree
6675 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.etree.cElementTree
6691 INFO: Processing hook hook-_elementtree
8204 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4
15583 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtGui
20779 INFO: Processing hook hook-matplotlib.backends
21200 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtCore
21309 INFO: Processing hook hook-_tkinter
21402 INFO: checking Tree
21402 INFO: building because out00-Tree.toc missing or bad
21402 INFO: building Tree out00-Tree.toc
21573 INFO: checking Tree
21573 INFO: building because out01-Tree.toc missing or bad
21573 INFO: building Tree out01-Tree.toc
21762 INFO: Processing hook hook-tables
22776 INFO: Processing hook hook-sqlalchemy
23243 INFO: Processing hook hook-sqlite3
24148 INFO: Processing hook hook-IPython
24615 INFO: Processing hook hook-zmq
24819 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtSvg
24881 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.dom
24912 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.dom.domreg
26394 INFO: Processing hook hook-docutils
26721 INFO: Processing hook hook-pygments.lexers
26753 INFO: Processing hook hook-pygments.styles
28125 INFO: Processing hook hook-sphinx
28157 INFO: Processing hook hook-jinja2
28859 INFO: Processing hook hook-scipy.io.matlab
29592 INFO: Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise
29592 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
29592 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
29592 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py
29733 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_Image.py
29826 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py
29920 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_mpldata.py
30013 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py
30122 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_PIL_Image.py
30200 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_Tkinter.py
30279 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py
30668 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
30668 WARNING: Assembly not found
30668 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
31152 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
31152 WARNING: Assembly not found
31152 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
32915 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.pyd dependency of C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\z
mq\devices\monitoredqueue.pyd
33102 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
33102 WARNING: Assembly not found
33102 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
34944 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.MFC to dependent assemblies of final executable
35036 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
35036 INFO: Found manifest C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.
manifest
35036 INFO: Searching for file mfc90.dll
35036 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc90.dll
35036 INFO: Searching for file mfc90u.dll
35036 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc90u.dll
35036 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90.dll
35036 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfcm90.dll
35036 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90u.dll
35036 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfcm90u.dll
36690 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
36690 WARNING: Assembly not found
36690 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
36986 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
36986 WARNING: Assembly not found
36986 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
37128 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
37128 WARNING: Assembly not found
37128 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
37251 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
37251 WARNING: Assembly not found
37251 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
37845 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
37845 WARNING: Assembly not found
37861 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
38203 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
38203 WARNING: Assembly not found
38203 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
38250 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
38328 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
38328 WARNING: Assembly not found
38328 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
41230 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\python27.dll
41838 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\KNN\build\KNN\warnKNN.txt
41978 INFO: checking PYZ
41978 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
41978 INFO: building PYZ (ZlibArchive) out00-PYZ.toc
52009 INFO: checking PKG
52009 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
52009 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
87062 INFO: checking EXE
87062 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because KNN.exe missing
87062 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
87062 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\KNN\dist\KNN.exe

C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\KNN>pyinstaller --onedir KNN.py
19 INFO: wrote C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\KNN\KNN.spec
32 INFO: Testing for ability to set icons, version resources...
49 INFO: ... resource update available
49 INFO: UPX is not available.
65 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
150 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
151 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
200 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
286 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
352 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
361 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
638 INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib
641 INFO: Processing hook hook-email
718 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
881 WARNING: library python%s%s required via ctypes not found
980 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\KNN
980 INFO: checking Analysis
981 INFO: building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc non existent
981 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
983 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable
1065 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
1065 WARNING: Assembly not found
1065 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
1154 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
1154 WARNING: Assembly not found
1154 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
1243 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstall
er\loader\_pyi_bootstrap.py
1253 INFO: Processing hook hook-os
1264 INFO: Processing hook hook-site
1276 INFO: Processing hook hook-encodings
1359 INFO: Processing hook hook-time
1362 INFO: Processing hook hook-cPickle
1411 INFO: Processing hook hook-_sre
1502 INFO: Processing hook hook-cStringIO
1578 INFO: Processing hook hook-codecs
1861 INFO: Processing hook hook-httplib
1864 INFO: Processing hook hook-email
1943 INFO: Processing hook hook-email.message
2111 WARNING: library python%s%s required via ctypes not found
2236 INFO: Processing hook hook-pydoc
2282 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstall
er\loader\pyi_importers.py
2369 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstall
er\loader\pyi_archive.py
2453 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstall
er\loader\pyi_carchive.py
2533 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\PyInstall
er\loader\pyi_os_path.py
2540 INFO: Analyzing KNN.py
2632 INFO: Processing hook hook-distutils
2754 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml
2809 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.sax
2832 INFO: Processing hook hook-pyexpat
3381 INFO: Processing hook hook-matplotlib
3648 INFO: Processing hook hook-sysconfig
3651 INFO: Processing hook hook-parser
4522 INFO: Processing hook hook-setuptools
4703 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32com
4710 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32com.client
4720 INFO: Processing hook hook-pythoncom
4772 INFO: Processing hook hook-pywintypes
4862 INFO: Processing hook hook-win32ui
5375 INFO: Processing hook hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph
5490 INFO: Processing hook hook-PIL
5506 INFO: Processing hook hook-PIL.Image
5598 INFO: Processing hook hook-Image
5823 INFO: Processing hook hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin
6670 INFO: Processing hook hook-pytz
6871 INFO: Processing hook hook-lxml.etree
6877 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.etree.cElementTree
6891 INFO: Processing hook hook-_elementtree
8502 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4
8503 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtGui
13757 INFO: Processing hook hook-matplotlib.backends
14190 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtCore
14305 INFO: Processing hook hook-_tkinter
14415 INFO: checking Tree
14417 INFO: building because out00-Tree.toc missing or bad
14417 INFO: building Tree out00-Tree.toc
14579 INFO: checking Tree
14579 INFO: building because out01-Tree.toc missing or bad
14579 INFO: building Tree out01-Tree.toc
14777 INFO: Processing hook hook-tables
15864 INFO: Processing hook hook-sqlalchemy
16348 INFO: Processing hook hook-sqlite3
17246 INFO: Processing hook hook-IPython
17729 INFO: Processing hook hook-zmq
17938 INFO: Processing hook hook-PyQt4.QtSvg
18002 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.dom
18023 INFO: Processing hook hook-xml.dom.domreg
19514 INFO: Processing hook hook-docutils
19856 INFO: Processing hook hook-pygments.lexers
19885 INFO: Processing hook hook-pygments.styles
21273 INFO: Processing hook hook-sphinx
21298 INFO: Processing hook hook-jinja2
22033 INFO: Processing hook hook-scipy.io.matlab
22779 INFO: Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise
22779 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
22779 INFO: Looking for run-time hooks
22783 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py
22930 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_Image.py
23013 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_mplconfig.py
23105 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_mpldata.py
23184 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py
23279 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_PIL_Image.py
23361 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_Tkinter.py
23440 INFO: Analyzing rthook C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\P
yInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py
23825 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
23825 WARNING: Assembly not found
23826 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
24313 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
24315 WARNING: Assembly not found
24315 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
26085 WARNING: lib not found: libzmq.pyd dependency of C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\z
mq\devices\monitoredqueue.pyd
26263 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
26263 WARNING: Assembly not found
26263 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
27958 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.MFC to dependent assemblies of final executable
28030 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
28032 INFO: Found manifest C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\Microsoft.VC90.MFC.
manifest
28032 INFO: Searching for file mfc90.dll
28032 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc90.dll
28033 INFO: Searching for file mfc90u.dll
28033 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc90u.dll
28033 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90.dll
28033 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfcm90.dll
28035 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90u.dll
28035 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfcm90u.dll
29723 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
29723 WARNING: Assembly not found
29723 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
30019 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
30019 WARNING: Assembly not found
30019 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
30160 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
30160 WARNING: Assembly not found
30160 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
30285 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
30285 WARNING: Assembly not found
30285 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
30846 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
30846 WARNING: Assembly not found
30846 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
31174 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
31174 WARNING: Assembly not found
31174 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
31220 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
31299 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none ...
31299 WARNING: Assembly not found
31299 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found
34091 INFO: Using Python library C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\python27.dll
34714 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\KNN\build\KNN\warnKNN.txt
34792 INFO: checking PYZ
34792 INFO: rebuilding out00-PYZ.toc because out00-PYZ.pyz is missing
34792 INFO: building PYZ (ZlibArchive) out00-PYZ.toc
44621 INFO: checking PKG
44621 INFO: rebuilding out00-PKG.toc because out00-PKG.pkg is missing
44621 INFO: building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
44652 INFO: checking EXE
44652 INFO: rebuilding out00-EXE.toc because KNN.exe missing
44652 INFO: building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
44667 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\Patrick\Google Drive\KNN\build\KNN\KNN.exe
44698 INFO: checking COLLECT
44698 INFO: building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
```

Based on these lines:

```
    35036 INFO: Searching for file mfc90.dll
    35036 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc90.dll
    35036 INFO: Searching for file mfc90u.dll
    35036 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc90u.dll
    35036 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90.dll
    35036 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfcm90.dll
    35036 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90u.dll
    35036 INFO: Found file C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
```

It appears that Pyinstaller is looking for the windows .dlls it needs in the `C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin` directory, so I tried copying `msvcp90.dll` and `msvcm90.dll` there as per this question on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446124/solvedbundle-just-onefile).

But I still get the same errors. Additionally I also get the same errors when using the Pyinstaller command `pyinstaller --onedir MyScript.py` instead.

Does anyone know how I can resolve this error?

## Update

I ran the same pyinstaller command on my laptop at home and I do no get any errors whatsoever. Same python versions using Anaconda distribution on Windows 7. Without giving the full log, here is the section that contained the errors previously discussed:

```
87871 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0
.21022.8_none ...
87881 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_
1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b.manifest
87911 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
87921 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e
3b_9.0.21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcr90.dll
87921 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
87921 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e
3b_9.0.21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcp90.dll
87921 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
87930 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e
3b_9.0.21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcm90.dll
88631 INFO: Analyzing C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lo
ader\_pyi_bootstrap.py
```

So basically on my laptop this is the directory where the `msvcr90.dll`, `msvcp90.dll`, and `msvcm90.dll` were found. I'll have to check out this directory on my computer at work and see what I can find.

Comment: I've got this exact same problem with Windows 7 64-bit using Anaconda and PyInstaller. Did you get to a resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this and the SO help looks thin, so this is what I know so far.  I am past this error with a nasty hack.  The pyinstaller is getting the exact version number of the msvcr90.dll from the python.exe manifest but this is not the version that any link I found downloads (9.0.21022.8).  I used [ResEdit](http://csi-windows.com/toolkit/240-great-pe-editor-for-internal-manifests)  to update the manifest to use version 9.0.30729.6161 which is what is in my \Windows\winsxs directory.  Now it builds but fails with a similar error at runtime, so I think the same thing is happening with some other file (the error is reported for python27.dll).

Update: This was a good clue but I was able to go back to the stock python and get it all to work seemlessly by following the advice [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyinstaller/WNsoU9YfM-Q) and installing the x64 version of the MS Visual C++ redistribution vcredist_x64_2008 (from Microsoft).  Seems to be that the package stuff gets really confused if you have a mix of 32 bit and 64 bit stuff (i.e. instead of failing it picked up the 32 bit versions).

Comment: Interesting. Well I don't have this error anymore for who knows why really. I think reinstalling python at some point could have fixed the problem. It sounds like you're on the right track with it though. Update back if you end up resolving this

Comment: I was able to resolve my errors by installing the [VC++ redistribution package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336) as Ken described in his update. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. I installed the `VC++ redistribution package` from the link, copied the 3 `.dll` files to `site packages\Pythonwin`. Though, it doesn't give the previous error (`amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8 not found`), but still the created `exe` doesn't do what's it supposed to do. On running the `exe`, it simply opens the command prompt and the command prompt vanishes quickly after displaying a message. I am able to read this much of it - `file already exits it should not pyconfig`

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Here is my way to tackle this.

have a look at this error :-
file C:\Windows\WinSxS***amd64***_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e
3b_***9.0.21022***.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcr90.dll

The bold portion will tell you that which **Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable** package needs to be downloaded.

Now Make a google search with
Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable **x64 9.0.21022**

You will get the relevant links to download the package. I got this one:-
https://npackd.appspot.com/p/com.microsoft.VisualCPPRedistributable64/9.0.21022

Do uninstall any previous unnecessary versions if any.

Install the downloaded package.

Run your pyinstaller command. It should work now.

Hope it works for anyone out there.