# Python PyInstaller exe not working

Tags: python, windows, exe, pyinstaller

Specs:

Anaconda

Python 2.7

Windows 8.1

I created a GUI using Tkinter. Here are my import statements:

## wave.py

```
import pywt
import cv2
import numpy
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import cPickle
import Queue
import os
```

## gui.py

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import Tkinter
import tkFileDialog
import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import wave (wave.py, created by me)
import threading
```

I tried creating an `.exe`:

```
pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed gui.py
```

which returned me the error similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911011/create-exe-with-pyinstaller-error-assembly-amd64-microsoft-vc90-crt-1fc8b3b9a1):

`amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none not found`.

Going by the answers there, I installed the redistribution package and copied `msvcm90.dll`,`msvcp90.dll`,`msvcr90.dll` to `C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin`.

Now, on doing `pyinstaller.exe --onefile gui.py`there are no errors, but the created `exe` does nothing. On clicking the `exe`, the command prompt appears for a few seconds, and then vanishes after displaying some message. I could read only this much `already exists while it should not pyconfig`

I have no understanding as of now that what all goes into making an `exe` so I cannot correct the mistake. I would appreciate it if someone explains the process, even in a brief way.

I think this has got something to do with the MSVC redistribution I have, which I must tell I have more than 1 (don't know if this is creating a problem, since I have both x64 and x86):

[image: These all are the MSVC I have]

How can I correct the problem? I could have posted `cmd` snips but I have messed up the system bad and now it's throwing all kind of errors.

## Edit:

after installing the redistribution pack and copying `dll`s to `site packages/pythonwin`, it is also showing (but wasn't showing previously):

```
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\build.py", line 409, in __init__
raise ValueError("script '%s' not found" % script)
ValueError: script 'windowed' not found
```